# Get order data afterPlaceOrder on checkout page

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

Im trying to get the order increment id after success place order is triggered. This is my method-renderer file:

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/redirect-on-success',
    'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList',
    'mage/url',
    'mage/translate',
],
function (Component, quote, customer, fullScreenLoader, totals, redirectOnSuccessAction, messageList, url, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Module_MyModule/payment/custom_module'
        },
        afterPlaceOrder: function () {
            // HERE I WANT THE ORDER INCREMENT ID
        },

        successPlaceOrder: function () {
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
            this.placeOrder();
        },
        placeOrder: function() {
            let context = this;
            context.successPlaceOrder();
        }
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Better way was use a controller to get the order info. Based on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141974/custom-place-order-redirect-with-orderid

Answer (score 0):

You can catch an event to get order data when the payment is successful.
You can try the event: checkout_onepage_controller_success_action